# How to access Exchange calendar from asp application

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, exchange-server, impersonation

I have been tasked with writing a .NET application that has to have access to a users exchange calendar. This application will only be accessed from the local network and I need to have to automatically use the current domain users credentials to access exchange.

I have the following code but I get an error saying "The account does not have permission to impersonate the requested user."

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
string exchange = "exchangeWSURL";
service.Url = new Uri(exchange);
service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.PrincipalName, userid);
service.PreAuthenticate = true;
CalendarView cal = new CalendarView(startDate, startDate.AddDays(7));
FindItemsResults<Appointment> findResults = service.FindAppointments(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, cal);
```

It looks like I am doing something wrong. I was hoping to now have to turn on impersonation for all users on the domain.

Any help would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

This article provides what you seem to be looking for. Take note of the paragraph on "Impersonation". This seems to suit your needs perfectly.

[ASP.NET and Exchange tips and samples](http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2005/04/aspnet-and-exchange-tips-and-samples.html)

Answer (score 0):

Copied from MSDN:

> You must configure the Exchange server to allow impersonation before
>   your application can use impersonation. For more information, see
>   Configuring Exchange Impersonation (Exchange Web Services).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633680(v=exchg.80).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204095(exchg.140).aspx